# Issues connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some problems with connecting to my Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Here is  my code:

```
private void conButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString;

    SqlConnection appMessage;
    conString = @"Data Source=DHRANTONIUSVICT\SQLA; Initial Catalog=AppMessage; User ID=myid; Password=mypass; Server=localhost\sqlexpress";

    appMessage = new SqlConnection(conString);

    try
    {
         appMessage.Open();
         MessageBox.Show("Connection is stable. Starting up the engines...");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection to HQ is unstable. Need engineers ASAP!");
    }
```

Somehow I can't connect to my SQL Server.
What am I doing wrong?

And please, bare in mind that I`m new to this SQL stuff.

Comment: And what exception did you get?

Comment: that it can't connect.

Comment: The problem is solved!

Comment: Your title says insert data, but your code is not even inserting anything

Comment: that doesn't matter at all James. It's just to test the connection

Comment: It does matter, since your problem isn't inserting data. It's connecting to the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use DataSource or Server.You are using both

```
conString = @"Data Source=DHRANTONIUSVICT\SQLA; Initial Catalog=AppMessage; User ID=myid; Password=mypass ";
```

please refer to the SqlConnection.ConnectionString [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx):